# How to download this kind of embedded video?

Tags: google-chrome, video, download, curl, url

I wanted to download this video, i tried chrome dev-tool to isolate the url.

Then searched it; but it showed me this

[image]

why i cant download this video? is there any alternate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the image you posted, the video owner denied you from directly accessing the URL. You probably should not try to circumvent this. If you really need the video, contact the owner.